# How to find the x0 and x1 after matrix move,rotate and scale

Tags: matrices, computer-science, transformation

I have an exercise that says if after the image move(that is the matrix and has the values x0,x1) or translation and then we rotate it for θ (Theta) degree and we scale it for (S0,S1) we have the matrix

[Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkSqK.png)

T =
$\begin{bmatrix}0.951623 & 0.443749 & -6.97686\\-0.401487 & 0.860992 & -2.29753\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Find x0,x1,θ and S0,S1

Comment: If the transformation includes only multiplying with a matrix, it doesn't involve any translation. Only scaling and rotation. Also, with a rotation, the determinant of the matrix is $1$. What is the determinant of this matrix?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use MathJax instead of links to external pictures:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Yes but the exercise says: Lets assume that we moved the image for the values (x0,x1) And then we rotated it for 0 degrees And then we scaled it for (S0,S1) And after all these steps we got as an result the matrix witch is in the link @MattiP.

Comment: I am still learning how to use MathJax thanks for the advice @YukiJ

Comment: $T$ is incompatible with a 0-degree rotation. Do you mean $\theta$?

Comment: @amd yeah that`s what i mean sorry for my mistake the picture is a little  bit blurry so it is not very seeable

Answer (score 0):

Write out the generic matrices for the three unknown transformations individually and compute their product. The brute-force way to obtain a solution is then to set this equal to $T$ and solve the resulting system of equations, but there’s a more systematic approach that might be more manageable.

Examine the generic transformation matrix that you computed above and look for patterns that might help you isolate some of the parameters. For example, what do you get when you square and add the first two elements of the first row? Does that suggest a way to compute one of the parameters of this transformation from $T$? Then, peel back the layers. Once you’ve found the scale factors, you can undo that part of the transformation and work on finding the rotation angle. After determining that, undo the rotation and you’ll have the translation.